# Subsequent ordered HTTP calls

Tags: swift, api, http, swiftui

I'm building a simple iOS client for HackerNews. I'm using [their APIs](https://github.com/HackerNews/API), according to which I'll be able to get the ordered post IDs (sorted by new, best and top) and a single post item passing the ID to the request. The problem I'm facing is the following: how can I, once I get the IDs array, make an HTTP call for every post in an ordered fashion? With the way I currently implemented it, I'm not having any luck.
E.g. say the IDs array is [3001, 3002, 3003, 3004]. I tried calling the method to get those posts inside a for loop issuing dispatch groups and dispatch semaphores, but I still get them unordered, like the call for item 3003 completes before 3002, and so on.

The methods I'm using:

```
@Published var posts: [Post] = []
    
    func getPosts(feedType: FeedType){
        posts = []
        
        self.getFeedIDs(feedType: feedType).subscribe{ ids in
            let firstFifteen = ids[0...15]
            
            let dGroup = DispatchGroup()
            let dQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "network-queue")
            let dSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            
            dQueue.async {
                for id in firstFifteen{
                    dGroup.enter()
                    self.getPost(id: id).subscribe{ post in
                        self.posts.append(post)
                        dSemaphore.signal()
                        dGroup.leave()
                    }
                    dSemaphore.wait()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getFeedIDs(feedType: FeedType) -> Observable<[Int]> {
        return self.execute(url: URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/\(feedType)stories.json")!)
    }
    
    func getPost(id: Int) -> Observable<Post>{
        return self.execute(url: URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(id).json")!)
    }

func execute <T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> Observable<T> {
        return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { res, _, _ in
                guard let data = res, let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else {
                    return
                }
                
                observer.onNext(decoded)
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
            task.resume()
            
            return Disposables.create {
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semaphore makes no sense and is inefficient anyway.

Use the same pattern which Apple suggests in conjunction with TaskGroups: Collect the data in a dictionary and after being notified sort the data by the dictionary keys

```
func getPosts(feedType: FeedType){
    var postData = [Int:Post]()
    posts = []
     
     self.getFeedIDs(feedType: feedType).subscribe{ ids in
         let firstFifteen = ids[0...15]
         
         let dGroup = DispatchGroup()
         
         for (index, element) in firstFifteen.enumerated() {
             dGroup.enter()
             self.getPost(id: element).subscribe{ post in
                 postData[index] = post
                 dGroup.leave()
             }   
         }
         
         dGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
             for key in postData.keys.sorted() {
                 posts.append(postData[key]!)
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Just tried this answer but it doesn't seem to work either. I added a print of the IDs array and of each post ID and this is what I get: `ids [33070499, 33070330, 33070314, 33070313, 33070254, 33070247, 33070241, 33070229, 33070205, 33070204, 33070171, 33070159, 33070146, 33070141, 33070131, 33070120]
post id 33070499
post id 33070241
post id 33070314
post id 33070330
post id 33070254
post id 33070313
post id 33070247
post id 33070229
post id 33070205
post id 33070204
post id 33070171
post id 33070146
post id 33070159
post id 33070141
post id 33070131
post id 33070120
`

Comment: Please insert a line `print(key)` inside the `for key in postData.keys.sorted()` body. There the ids must be sorted and also the posts in `posts`.

Comment: I did, and it doesn't print anything. Seems like the notify never gets called.

Comment: Nothing fancy, really. If it put a print after `enter()` and `leave()`, I get 15 consecutive enter prints followed by a leave after every `postData[id] = post` assignment, 15 in total.

Comment: Please see the edit. You don't need the custom queue.

Comment: We're almost there: the articles are printed in order, just in reverse. Any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: Sort the keys descending: `for key in postData.keys.sorted(by: >) {`

Comment: That actually works but only on the "New" section (which has them ordered by id). I think there has been a bit of a misunderstanding. I want them ordered by the order in which they're arranged on the IDs array, which is only descending on the "New" endpoint. "Top" and "Best" aren't ordered like that. For example, let `ids = [5, 6, 7]`, that might be the same order as in the New endpoint, but they might be `[6, 7, 5]` in Top and `[5, 7, 6]` in Best. Again, my aim is to have them ordered with the same order as they are on the IDs array which I get via the New, Best and Top endpoints.

Comment: Understood. See the new edit. It iterates the indices of the array. Probably you have to sort the keys in ascending order as initially suggested.

Comment: That seems to be it! Thank you so very much!